# How could I stream a video in my website?

Tags: html, web, video-streaming, object-tag

I tried to stream a video from my browser using the object tag in HTML, but when I build the project, the video is not being played. Here is the piece of code:

```
<object id="Player" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"> 
    <param name="autoStart" value="True"> 
    <param name="URL" value=" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZZSsHQmz0E "/> 
    <param name="rate" value="1"/> 
    <param name="balance" value="0"/> 
    <param name="enabled" value="true"/> 
    <param name="enabledContextMenu" value="true"/> 
    <param name="fullScreen" value="false"/> 
    <param name="playCount" value="1"/> 
    <param name="volume" value="100"/> 
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got share->embem button in youtube that tells you what to write for it to stream. for this video its:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PZZSsHQmz0E"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: what i meant was not to embed but get the video information and get it displayed on to my player.

Comment: it worked with iframe. I thought iframe would show the entire webpage. :)